# Why is my bootstrap popover showing light grey text on white background?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

Why is the text in my popover showing as light grey on white background?
Is there a way to override the text in the popover to be black? I think it is picking up the style from a style tag, but I want to override the color for the popup.

Here's a snippet where it uses the popover:

```
<tr style="background:#5789c6; color:#FFF;">
<th>{{ Help.SUPPORTING_READS }}
    Supp. Reads (#)
</th>
```

Here's the JS:

```
<script>
    // Turn tooltips and popovers on
    $(function () {
        options = {
            delay: { show: 500, hide: 100 }, 
            trigger:'hover', 
            placement: 'top', 
            html: true,
        }
        $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip(options);
        $("[rel='popover']").popover(options);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the bootstrap popovers (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) and it looks like the div called *popover-content* is responsible for the styling:

```
.popover-content {
padding: 9px 14px; // that is bootstrap default
background: #5789c6;
color: #FFF;
}
```

This gives me a grey popover with white text. IS that what you meant?